# Control-m email alert for when the job is not triggered by spefic time

Tags: control-m

I'm exploring different options to send email notifications when the job is not started before 11:00 PM .

My job type is OS and it is dependent on other job(not owned by me), some time the source job run for long time and causing my job to wait , in this case I would like get a notification as my job is not started .

I could see there is a option in Actions tab --> Notifications before job completion --> when : Job not submitted by time , have different option to specify the time but in the Send notification section Don't have email as destination .

Could you please help me if we have  options to send email alert .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common requirement. It can be solved by creating custom shout destinations on the Control-M server. Any custom shout destination will show up in the list in your screenshot.

Custom shout destinations can be configured to send an email to a hardcoded email address among other things.

See following link for more details:
http://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.18/help/Main_help/en-US/index.htm#ShoutDestManager.htm